# What is the shape of this curve?

Tags: recreational-mathematics, conic-sections

Assume we have a cone, as shown on the left of the diagram, with its vertex at A and base a circle BC(C’)B passing through points B and C.

If we cut it around the line AC, expand it out , it’s a circular sector ACBC’A, where the original base circle BC(C’)B now is an arc CBC’, as shown on the right side .

If we cut the cone, the base BD(D’)B is an ellipse.

Now, if we still cut it along side AD, and expand it out. What is the shape of the curve DBD’ ?

[image]

Comment: See page 400 et seq. of https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/apostol388.pdf